# Continued Fraction $1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5+...}}}}$

Tags: continued-fractions

I arrived at this while solving for a Physics Problem.
$$1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}+...}}}}}}}}}$$

I was wondering whether this has a closed form.

I think the notation for this is,
$$[1:\frac{1}{2},3,\frac{1}{4},5,\frac{1}{6},...,]$$
I was not able to find much about it online.

EDIT:
[image]

This was the Physics Problem if anyone interested, though the physics is superficial here.

Comment: Is it even clear that such a continued fraction converges?

Comment: What was the physics problem?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Bcontinuedfractionk%28k%5E%28-1%29%5E%28k-1%29%2C+%28k%2C+2%2C+50%29%29

Comment: Doing it in Python I got that the sequence decreases and converges towards $2.485339738238447$.

Comment: Numerically, it converges to $4 / \log 5$.  But to prove it?

Comment: @mjqxxxx How come? WolframAlpha and Python says otherwise: $2.485339738238447
 $

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF.  We agree... those are the same value.  $4/\log 5 \approx 2.485339738238447$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought it was base $10$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I have added it into the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This expression can be evaluated with [Gauss' continued fraction](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.7.E1) :
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathbf{F}\left(a,b;c;z\right)}{\mathbf{F}\left(a,b+1;c+1;z\right)}=t_{0%
}-\cfrac{u_{1}z}{t_{1}-\cfrac{u_{2}z}{t_{2}-\cfrac{u_{3}z}{t_{3}-\cdots}}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
 t_n&=c+n\\
u_{2n+1}&=(a+n)(c-b+n)\\
u_{2n}&=(b+n)(c-a+n)
\end{align} and $\mathbf{F}$ is the regularized hypergeometric function.

In view of Gauss' formula, one may transform first
\begin{equation}
 L=1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}+...}}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
into an equivalent expression with linearly increasing coefficients $t_n$:
\begin{equation}
 L=1+\frac{4}{2+\frac{4}{3+\frac{16}{4+\frac{16}{5+\frac{36}{6+\frac{36}{7+\frac{64}{8+\frac{64}{9+\frac{100}{10+...}}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
then, by choosing $c=1, a=1, b=0,z=-4$, we have
\begin{align}
 t_n&=n+1\\
u_{2n+1}&=(n+1)^2\\
u_{2n}&=n^2
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{equation}
 L=\frac{{}_2F_1(1,0;1,-4)}{{}_2F_1(1,1;2,-4)}=\frac{1}{{}_2F_1(1,1;2,-4)}
\end{equation}
Since [(DLMF)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E1)
\begin{equation}
{}_2F_1\left(1,1;2;z\right)=-z^{-1}\ln\left(1-z\right)
\end{equation}
it comes
\begin{equation}
 L=\frac{4}{\ln5}
\end{equation}
as expected from the numerical evaluations in the comments.

Comment: Hi Paul ! One more nice solution. Cheers   :-)

Comment: Hi Claude! Merci and cheers...